# how to use this context in angularjs views?

Tags: angularjs, this

well, I don't know if something like this is possible or not? so let's just ask and find out.

```
<input name="link" ng-model="addItemLink" ng-class="{'input-blink': this.$pristine}" />
```

in general, do we ever get able to use keyword `this` in angular views?? and could you put me on a path to achieve something similar here??

P.S: I already know about normal angular form validation and how to properly access $pristine. I want to know about `this` here??
uh and I guess $pristine is totally undefined outside a form, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> do we ever get able to use keyword this in angular views

Yes, of course, however it's not used often, because it doesn't mean what we are used to think `this` points to. In Angular view directives (in attributes) `this` points to current `$scope` object and not current HTMLElement object.

So for example, you could fix your code using `this` (`myForm` name of the `form`):

```
<input name="link" ng-model="addItemLink" ng-class="{'input-blink': this.myForm.link.$pristine}" />
```

But in this case, `this` is pretty redundant. There might be rear situations when you need to use `this`, for example to use dynamic name of the model:

```
$scope.name = 'user';
```

and in HTML:

```
<input ng-model="this[name]">
```

is equivalent to manually hardcoded `user` as model `<input ng-model="user">`.